# (jquery3.0 up): window.load v.s. document.ready and wrong operation on window.load

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-3

I have already search for several websites through net. I still have the problem that: I choose `window.load` to execute the following code, but my blanket of height is always undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Tobyliao</title>
      <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript"> // $(window).on('load', function() { ... }); $(document).ready(function(){ // $('#div1').html('Height='+$('img1').height()+'Width='+$(img1‌​).width()); }); $(window).on("load", function(){ $('#div1').html('Height='+$('img1').height()+'<br/>'+'Wid‌​th='+$(img1).width()‌​); }); </script> 
      <div id="div1"></div>
      <img src="microsd.jpg" id="img1"> 
   </head>
   <body> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Tobyliao</title>
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // $(window).on('load', function() { ... }); 

  $(document).ready(function(){
   // $('#div1').html('Height='+$('img1').height()+'Width='+$(img1).width());
  });
  $(window).on("load", function(){
   $('#div1').html('Height='+$('img1').height()+'<br/>'+'Width='+$(img1).width());
  });
 </script>
 <div id="div1"></div>
 <img src="microsd.jpg" id="img1">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [JQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) docs it looks like their example shows the syntax as:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});
```